# Default Encoding for Default Directory Viewer

Tags: apache

When there is no index.html Apache provides a default directory viewer, however I want it to be encoded in utf-8 to show the filenames correctly. Adding AddDefaultCharset utf-8 to httpd.conf and /extra/httpd-autoindex.conf does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration should help

```
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
```

details : [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions)

Comment: this configuration is not in my httpd.conf, where this configurtation is done

Comment: @Rahul Mehta - you can try `<Directory your_directory>IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8</Directory>`